# Как управлять правами доступа к журналам Windows 10 через реестр?

Tags: windows, безопасность, логирование, реестр

Пытаюсь решить задачу управления доступа к журналам через реестр. По этой [ссылке](https://support.microsoft.com/ru-ru/help/323076/how-to-set-event-log-security-locally-or-by-using-group-policy) представлена инструкция от Microsoft, но она, вероятно, актуальна для Windows Server 2003, но не для Windows 10.

Вопрос: как осуществить подобное на Windows 10? Какие ключи отвечают за права доступа к журналам на этой ОС?

Comment: Судя по справке встроенной утилиты **wevtutil**, она позволяет с помощью XML-файлов изменять конфигурации журналов, в параметры которых входит **channelAccess**. Его синтаксис оформляется в формате **SDDL**. Поможет ли указанная утилита в решении Вашей задачи?

Comment: @Daemon-5 я как раз работаю с ней, но дело в том, что мне нужно узнать, какие именно значения **в реестре** отвечают за эти права. Это нужно чтобы потом писать напрямую в реестр с помощью собственной программы, не привлекая стороннее ПО, такое как wevtutil.

Comment: Я думаю, что такие сведения, согласно логике дискретной модели доступа Windows, хранятся в метаинформации ветвей реестра. Они заданы для каждой ветви, которая хранит параметры журнала. То есть права на доступ к журналу **Приложений** заданы в правах доступа к ветви **HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\EventLog\Application\Application**. Права доступа к **Аудит** -  **HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\EventLog\Security**, etc. Поэтому Вам нужно работать с правами ветвей реестра, а не с их значениями.

Comment: @Daemon-5 спасибо, интересное предположение. Я опробую его и отпишусь о результате.

Answer (score 0):

После нескольких дней поисков оказалось, что инструкция, представленная по прикреплённой [ссылке](https://support.microsoft.com/ru-ru/help/323076/how-to-set-event-log-security-locally-or-by-using-group-policy) всё ещё актуальна. Проблема была в том, что, по примеру других значений в реестре, используемых для схожих целей, я записывал в `CustomSD` SDDL в двоичном формате, когда нужно было вписать его просто строкой.

P.S. Иногда решения оказываются проще, чем ожидалось.